# Unable to create a parquet hive table with a column data type 'STRING'

Tags: hadoop, hive, parquet

I am using hive-0.12. I successfully created a parquet table using the below query.

```
hive> create table ptest1 (a INT, b DOUBLE) 
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'parquet.hive.serde.ParquetHiveSerDe' 
stored as INPUTFORMAT 'parquet.hive.DeprecatedParquetInputFormat'
OUTPUTFORMAT 'parquet.hive.DeprecatedParquetOutputFormat';
OK
Time taken: 0.124 seconds
```

But when I am using 'STRING' as column data type it is failing.

```
hive> create table ptest1 (a INT, b STRING) 
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'parquet.hive.serde.ParquetHiveSerDe' 
stored as INPUTFORMAT 'parquet.hive.DeprecatedParquetInputFormat' 
OUTPUTFORMAT 'parquet.hive.DeprecatedParquetOutputFormat'; 
FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask. 
Could not initialize class org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.serde.primitive.ParquetPrimitiveInspectorFactory
```

Pls suggest what might be wrong here.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem of mine by adding below few jars to hive.

```
add jar parquet-avro-1.2.5.jar;
add jar parquet-cascading-1.2.5.jar;
add jar parquet-column-1.2.5.jar;
add jar parquet-common-1.2.5.jar;
add jar parquet-encoding-1.2.5.jar;
add jar parquet-generator-1.2.5.jar;
add jar parquet-hadoop-1.2.5.jar;
add jar parquet-hive-1.2.5.jar;
add jar parquet-pig-1.2.5.jar;
add jar parquet-scrooge-1.2.5.jar;
add jar parquet-test-hadoop2-1.2.5.jar;
add jar parquet-thrift-1.2.5.jar;
add jar parquet-format-1.0.0.jar;
```

Now its working fine. Thank You.

Comment: I had to give full path of the jar